# Erro com biblioteca Picasso

Tags: android

Eu tenho um problema com meu codigo e não consigo encontrar. As imagens não aparecem usando a biblioteca Picasso.

Não posso ver o problema no debug porque durante o processo aparece esta mensagem:

***Source not found
The source attachment does not contain the source for the file PathClassLoader.class***

Segue a classe que aparece o erro:

```html
public class AdaptadorLista extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<Jogo> itens;
 private View viewSelecionada;
 private int gols=0;
 private TextView txtPlacarSelecionado;
 private boolean btMaisPressionado = false;
 private boolean btMenosPressionado = false;
 private ItemSuporte itemSuporte;
 private LinearLayout linhaLista; 
 private Context context;

    
    
 public AdaptadorLista(Context context, List<Jogo> itens) {

  this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  this.itens = itens;
  this.context = context;
 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return itens.size();
 }

 @Override
 public Object getItem(int position) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return itens.get(position);
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return position;
 }

 
 private void importarImagem(ImageView imageView, String url) {

  Picasso.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .resize(70, 70)
    .centerCrop()
    .into(imageView);
  
 }
 
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  if(view==null){
   itemSuporte=new ItemSuporte();
   view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_lista, null);
   if(position % 2 == 0){
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.listaColor);
   }
   itemSuporte.btMaisGolsMandante=((ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btMaisGolsMandante));
   itemSuporte.btMaisGolsVisitante=((ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btMaisGolsVisitante));
   itemSuporte.btMenosGolsMandante=((ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btMenosGolsMandante));
   itemSuporte.btMenosGolsVisitante=((ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btMenosGolsVisitante));
   itemSuporte.txtPlacarMandante=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPlacarMandante));
   itemSuporte.txtPlacarVisitante=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPlacarVistante));
   itemSuporte.txtNomeMandante=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSimboloMandante));
   itemSuporte.txtNomeVisitante=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSimboloVisitante));
   itemSuporte.txtDataJogo=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDataJogo));
   //itemSuporte.txtLocalJogo=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtLocalJogo));
   itemSuporte.simboloMandante=((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgMandante));
   itemSuporte.simboloVisitante=((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgVisitante));
   view.setTag(itemSuporte);
  
  }else{
   itemSuporte= (ItemSuporte) view.getTag();
  }
  
  
 
  Jogo jogo = itens.get(position);
  importarImagem(itemSuporte.simboloMandante, jogo.getTimeMandante().getUrlImagemSimbolo());
  importarImagem(itemSuporte.simboloVisitante, jogo.getTimeVisitante().getUrlImagemSimbolo());
  itemSuporte.txtNomeMandante.setText(jogo.getTimeMandante().getSigla());
  itemSuporte.txtNomeVisitante.setText(jogo.getTimeVisitante().getSigla());
  itemSuporte.txtPlacarMandante.setText(Integer.toString(jogo.getGolsMandante()));
  itemSuporte.txtPlacarVisitante.setText(Integer.toString(jogo.getGolsVisitante()));
  itemSuporte.txtDataJogo.setText(jogo.getData());
```

Comment: Caezar, esse código não parecer ter problemas. Esta tendo algum erro no Logcat? Como esta seu Manifest? Acessando uma dessas url's pelo browser, ela aparece sem problemas?

Answer (score 1):

Descobri o problema!
Era coma importação da classe. Estava importando a biblioteca picasso de outro projeto!